# SQL Server ID auto generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have two databases named `db1` and `db2` in SQL Server 2008.

Both have a table called `customers`. `db1.dbo.Customers` has 9000 records, and `db2.dbo.tblCustomers` has 3000 records.

I want to insert the 3000 records from `db2` into `db1.dbo.Customers`. But I want `db1.dbo.Customers` to automatically generate `Customerid`.

Would it be possible?

Comment: give the example of existing customer id in db1.Customers table

Comment: If `db1.dbo.Customers.CustomerID` is defined as a `INT IDENTITY` field - then yes, that's no problem at all. Is it??

Answer (score 1):

Do like this :

```
INSERT INTO db1.dbo.Customers ( {All Columns except Customerid} )
SELECT  {All Columns except Customerid} FROM db2.dbo.Customers
```

but remember `db1.dbo.Customers.Customerid` should be auto number !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() function to generate a value for each new row.